# Monitor progress of function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this function on the internet:

```
def combos(els, l):
    if l == 1:
        return [(k,) for k, v in els.items() if v]
    cs = []
    for e in els:
        nd = {k: v if k != e else v - 1 for k, v in els.items() if v}
        cs += [(e,)+c for c in combos(nd, l-1)]
    return cs
```

```
print(combos({'a': 2, 'b': 3}, 3))
```

And now I would like to somehow monitor the current progress of the function. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Create a "progress" object which will hold progress information, pass it to the function and update it within the function.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The problem I’m having with this is that the function calls itself within the function. So in the 2nd “run” it can’t find the object anymore. Is there a solution?

Comment: @zvone I thought I knew what this was supposed to do, but after running it, the result does not contain `('a', 'a', 'a')` like you would expect.Can you briefly explain what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: @dragonbobz You are asking the song guy. This is not my question ;)

Comment: @paul the fact that it is recursive makes it more complex, but the data can still be passed. There are going to be other problems as well, but you'll have to do it yourself and come back if you have some more specific question. As it is, the question is too broad.

Comment: @zvone my bad! :)